# How to write data into excel sheet vertically in java?

Tags: java, excel

I have a Map with key and value as 
key as "Date"
value as a "Bean".

Suppose i have bean as

```
    public class example{

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private long date;
    private String workAssigned;

    //getters & setters

    }

    I got a list of bean values.


    List<example> list = getDetails();

    i am iterating and forming a map .
    as
    for(example e : list)
{
    List<example> list=exampleMap.get(example.getDate());
                    if(list==null){
                        list = new ArrayList<example>();
                        exampleMap.put(example.getDate(), list);
                    }
                    list.add(e);
}

Now i got a map with date..
```

Excel code

```
int rows = 5;
for (Map.Entry<String, List<example>> entry:exampleMap.entrySet() ) {

            String  date=entry.getKey();
            excelSheet.mergeCells(0, rows, 4, rows);
            addLabel(excelSheet, maxcolumn, rows, date, timesLeftDate);
            rows++;
                            List<example> DataLists=entry.getValue();
                    for (example DataList : DataLists) {
                                excelSheet.mergeCells(maxcolumn, rows, maxcolumn+1, rows);
                                excelSheet.mergeCells(maxcolumn+2, rows, maxcolumn+3, rows);
                                addLabel(excelSheet, maxcolumn, rows, DataList.getName, timesLeft);
                                addLabel(excelSheet, maxcolumn+2, rows, DataList.getId(), timesCenter);
                                addLabel(excelSheet, maxcolumn+4, rows, DataList.getWorkAssigned(), timesCenter);
                                rows++;
                            }
                            rows++;
                        }
```

Now i need to write those values into xls..
    I have done but i am getting vertically like

```
Employee1                 Id           workAssigned

2016-04-15              
bhavani                12345651           read
Julian Thomak          46546546           write
Shiva                  54464646           read

2016-04-20              
Bhavani                5479844            write
Shiva                  4745654            read


But expected output:
                 ---------------------------------------------------------
                            2016-04-15                  2016-04-16
                  --------------------------------------------------------
Employee1                 Id     workAssigned     id        workassgigned
                   -------------------------------------------------------

bhavani                12345651     read        5479844      write
Julian Thomak          46546546     write
Shiva                  54464646     read        4745654       read
sahu                                            1024158       read
```

Hope you undersatnd.. Can anyone please help me solve this..

Comment: Without the code your creating your output we can only guess whats wrong. So show us what you've tried so far. Have a look here [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ok..I have updated the code

Comment: I think you should rethink your datamodel. IMHO a simple Map<String,List<example>> is not sufficient for the desired output. By the way: What do you use to write the excel? POI? JXL?

Comment: i use JXL ................